# Properties.Resources after 'dotnet publish' doesn't return text file contents

Tags: c#, .net-core, resources

I have a [project on github](https://github.com/BenHall-7/paracobNET) set up to build via appveyor. In the build script I use `dotnet publish` to package all the dependencies. The issues are occurring for the NET Core project "prcScript", where I added a Resources.resx file via Visual Studio (2019) to contain some text files (like the application help text, in Help.txt). In the builds from `dotnet publish`, Properties.Resources.[name of resource] is returning the resource information instead of the file contents.

This issue doesn't happen on my own builds from Visual Studio (I use Community 2019). As far as I know, this doesn't have to do with the Build Action of the files either (but if I need to I might just try to fall back on Embedded Resource with reflection to handle this). Configuration set to either Release or Debug, with Platform set to AnyCPU behaved the same.

With any text file added to the Resources.resx, the resulting issue is straightforward since I'm simply printing to the console. In the command line, use `dotnet prcScript.dll -h`, and when this code runs...:

```cs
case "-h":
case "-help":
    Console.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.Help);
    break;
```

It prints `..\Help.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8` on builds from `dotnet publish`. On Visual Studio builds, it prints the contents of the file correctly:

```
prcScript: edit params through lua
required: [script file] (allows multiple files)
optional:
  -h = print help text
       (alias: -help)
  -a = print lua api
       (alias: -api)
  -l = load label file [path]
  -s = sandbox lua environment (prevents running unsafe code)
       (alias: -safe | -sandbox)
```

EDIT: this question still stands, but I've updated my repo to use the Embedded Resource + Reflection method. If you happen to want to test on the project, just checkout commit fe3838819145346d55b4ed19887783442a76e088 first

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?